# Bootstrap columns not get alligned when using columns of varying height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have  4 divs, div 2 is very lengthy,
div 1,3,4 are of equal sizes,
I want them to display in a compact form,
but it displays full contents of div2  then only displaying div3 ,it displays div 3 as a new row after all the contents of first row

```
    <div class ="row"> 
      <div class="col-xs-12"> //content 1 </div> 
      <div class="col-xs-12"> //content 2 </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class ="row"> 
      <div class="col-xs-12"> //content 3 </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class ="row"> 
     <div class="col-xs-12"> //content 4 </div> 
   </div>
```

please help me

Comment: `it displays div 3 as a new row after all the contents of first row` as it can be seen in your code, you are creating a new row after second div. Thats why the 3rd div is placed in a new row.

Comment: i want to display it as in a column
div1 div 3 div 4 and in next column div2

Comment: @SereneAbrahamMathew It is not clear from your comment what do you want. Create a image. and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem myself

Used row inside col div

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```